# The upgrade needs a total of 103 M free space on disk '/boot'

Tags: upgrade

Not enough free disk space

The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 103 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 12,4 M of disk space on '/boot'. You can remove old kernels using 'sudo apt autoremove' and you could also set COMPRESS=xz in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf to reduce the size of your initramfs.

i have tried deleting old kernels, clean up with tweak and boot does not empty

any hints of what and how i should delete from the following, are welcome

```
1,5M    /boot/abi-4.15.0-23-generic
213K    /boot/config-4.15.0-23-generic
221K    /boot/config-5.0.0-31-generic
221K    /boot/config-5.0.0-32-generic
6,7M    /boot/grub
57M     /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
13M     /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-62-generic
41M     /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-32-generic
12K     /boot/lost+found
180K    /boot/memtest86+.bin
182K    /boot/memtest86+.elf
182K    /boot/memtest86+_multiboot.bin
4,3M    /boot/System.map-5.0.0-31-generic
4,3M    /boot/System.map-5.0.0-32-generic
8,5M    /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-32-generic
```

sudo du -sh /boot/* gives
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo du -sh /boot/*`. `sudo apt autoremove` should have cleared out some old kernels but sometimes things get gunged up.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete these (provided you boot into 5.0.0):

```
57M     /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
13M     /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-62-generic
```

You can use these commands:

```
sudo rm /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
sudo rm /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-62-generic
```

But first verify that you are not using the kernels 4.15.0 or 4.4.0 by running:

```
uname -a
```

Please note that normally it is not advised to delete these files manualy, though I have done it in the past multiple times without any problems, if you take the precautions mentioned (the purge command should do exactly the same, though as Oli said "sometimes things get gunged up").

Comment: with which command ? no luck with sudo apt get purge

Comment: @planetrocker Please see my updated answer

Comment: 5.0.0-32-generic do you provide freelance support ?

Comment: @planetrocker No, I do not. As you use 5.0.0 you are safe to delete the two files.

Comment: one time logged into a password protected Macintosh with no password - and windows are windows... holy ubuntu foundation but ubuntu needs updates

Comment: 1,5M /boot/abi-4.15.0-23-generic
221K /boot/config-5.0.0-32-generic
6,7M /boot/grub
41M /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-32-generic
12K /boot/lost+found
180K /boot/memtest86+.bin
182K /boot/memtest86+.elf
182K /boot/memtest86+_multiboot.bin
4,3M /boot/System.map-5.0.0-32-generic
8,5M /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-32-generic ------- can i delete anything else from the boot ? thanks !

Comment: The two files I suggested should have sufficed. You can delete anything that references a version number you are not using. So, most of the files you mention should not be deleted.

Comment: you are right, but after deleting entries we need sth like grub update and grub customizer to update cause my last update forgot could not update grub... but a new version was pushed and shall see what happens... if it goes bad with boot, will report, thanks

Comment: do you have any idea how we can put tickets to do for the next update ? one issue is that boot does not empty before updating and another is that grub does not get updated automatically... there are two issues which need some care

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: with a GUI on this web site or other similar ? this is a super bug

Comment: This website is not run by canonical, it is a Q&A site where users help users.

Comment: is there any official website ? cause we do rounds and rounds like stupids... do you get my point ? the same issues repeat to everyone. otherwise we have to go for another OS, but which one ?

Comment: buddy do you have time to investigate about rygel ? i really do not like this preinstalled package... its another shitty package for surveilance

Comment: @planetrocker You can uninstall it if you want. It is a DLNA server, nothing mystic about it.

Comment: it think it was transmitting desktop activity all alone... and there are many similar packages like this...

Comment: do you have any idea how to build the boot folder from the scratch because someone logged in my machine and deleted it ? i see just a grub folder inside boot folder

Comment: No, just open a new question. Commends are not supposed to be used as a forum.